# javascript slider not working on a magento home page

Tags: javascript, magento, slider

I am working on a couple different magento sites. I have implemented a slider on two of the sites but on a third one it is not working. I am guessing the javascript is conflicting with another file but I cannot figure out which one or why it's conflicting. I have included `var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();`, as i did on the other sites but it still will not work. You can check out one of the sites that it is working on [here](http://wrestlinguniverse.muvdigital.com), and the site where it is not working is [here](http://wadjetworldwide.com).

Comment: There are no Javascript errors being thrown but it looks like the slider images have been wrapped in paragraph tags in the example that isn't working.

Comment: @McNab: The way the slider is supposed to work is by inserting the images into a static block and then calling that block in the code. I see what you mean but I'm not sure how to make them not be in paragraphs

Comment: Turn off the WYSIWYG editor and re-add the images.  That should stop it adding any styling.

Comment: That's how I did add the images. Looking at the static block for both sites, the images are within a paragraph for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the `<p>` tags around the images within the static block by turning off the WYSIWYG. Even though it automatically adds the paragraph tags after you save it, that somehow worked.