# JavaScript slider not working, Magento static block

Tags: jquery, magento, static, slider, block

Although I found the same [question 4 years back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850629/javascript-slider-not-working-on-a-magento-home-page) which hasn't been answered what I am looking for, I am new in coding, I write this code with help of Google, my slider looks OK in frontend, I can drag the slider for next slide but not automatically sliding.

My code below:

```
<div class="block_banner_top">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="wrap_item">
<div class="item"><a href="#"> <img alt="" src="{{media url='home/slide01.jpg'}}" /> </a>
<div class="info"><a class="title" href="#">Rewards</a> 
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te vis error saepe, integre.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"> <img alt="" src="{{media url='home/slide02.jpg'}}" /> </a>
<div class="info"><a class="title" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te vis error saepe, integre.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"> <img alt="" src="{{media url='home/slide03.jpg'}}" /> </a>
<div class="info"><a class="title" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te vis error saepe, integre.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"> <img alt="" src="{{media url='home/slide04.jpg'}}" /> </a>
<div class="info"><a class="title" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te vis error saepe, integre.</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
        $('.block_banner_top div.wrap_item').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            itemsCustom: [ 
                [0, 1], 
                [480, 1], 
                [768, 1], 
                [992, 1], 
                [1200, 1] 
            ],
            pagination: true,
            slideSpeed : 4000,
            addClassActive: true,
            scrollPerPage: true,
            touchDrag: false,
        });

    });
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: @SamuelJMathew: your edit on this question looked like a rewrite, and that's too major a change, so I regarded it as safest to reject. Large changes might accidentally resolve a parsing bug that is the cause of a question in the first place. Unless code is really unreadable, please do not reformat it.

Comment: @halfer i edited the code inoder to make it mcve. i think it will help him to clearly explain the issue with others. Moreover i only changed the code with some images from lorempixel with his code.i perserved the bug with the code.

Comment: @Samuel, I appreciate why you did it, I read the edit message. I still think the edit was too major and is not a good habit to get into, for the reasons I've mentioned. If you want to show that to the OP, you can either put it on a pasteboard and add that in the comments with an explanatory link, or offer an answer which mentions your improvements at the same time.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for your suggestion. i will consider your comment next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your issue  correcly.

By default the `autoplay` option for the owl carousel is disabled or set to false. so you need to set it to true inoder to autoplay.
you can refer the owl carousel documentation regarding autoplay [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html)

Some people report some bugs regarding the case of the autoplay.
it is better to use `autoPlay` inseted of `autoplay`. you can see the updated code of your issue below with some images from lorempixel for better understanding.

Hope this will help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.block_banner_top div.wrap_item').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    itemsCustom: [
      [0, 1],
      [480, 1],
      [768, 1],
      [992, 1],
      [1200, 1]
    ],
    pagination: true,
    slideSpeed: 4000,
    addClassActive: true,
    scrollPerPage: true,
    touchDrag: false,
    autoPlay:true,
    autoplayTimeout: 1000
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="block_banner_top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="wrap_item">
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#"> <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" /> </a>
          <div class="info"><a class="title" href="#">Rewards</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te vis error saepe, integre.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#"> <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/" /> </a>
          <div class="info"><a class="title" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te vis error saepe, integre.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#"> <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/" /> </a>
          <div class="info"><a class="title" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te vis error saepe, integre.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#"> <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4/" /> </a>
          <div class="info"><a class="title" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te vis error saepe, integre.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there anyway to make this slider responsive ? slider break in mobile devices. Thanks in advance